# Non-procedural way of implementing ELT dependency logic

Tags: etl, snowflake

I have two tables with identical schema, `sales_primary` and `sales_secondary`:

| productID | trxnWeekStartDate | dollarAmt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-02-07 | 100 |

For a particular week, these two tables can both have a productID, only one table have that productID, or neither has that productID. The task is to merge the two tables using following logic:

- Keep everything in `sales_primary`
- For a particular week, if a productID appeared in both tables, we only take the row in `sales_primary`
- For a particular week, if a productID appeared only in `sales_secondary`, include it in the result only if that productID appeared last week in the primary table
- If some row in the secondary table was included in the result set because of the above logic, we consider it "natively" in the primary table when applying that logic for next week.

I have these two tables with multi-years of data and need to backfill the result table. I considered recursive CTE because this problem mimics a "hierarchy" in some way, but was stopped by various limitations of a recursive CTE (no subquery, no distinct, no aggregation).

Example:

`sales_primary`:

| productID | trxnWeekStartDate | dollarAmt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-02-07 | 100 |

`sales_secondary`:

| productID | trxnWeekStartDate | dollarAmt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-02-14 | 100 |
| 123 | 2021-02-21 | 100 |
| 123 | 2021-03-21 | 100 |
| 123 | 2021-03-28 | 100 |
| 456 | 2021-02-14 | 100 |
| 456 | 2021-02-21 | 100 |

`Expected result`:

| productID | trxnWeekStartDate | dollarAmt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-02-07 | 100 |
| 123 | 2021-02-14 | 100 |
| 123 | 2021-02-21 | 100 |

I know this can be solved using a loop, but still want to know if set-based operation is possible (and preferred over procedural way)? I'm using Snowflake.

Answer (score 1):

This should do it without a cursor or loop.  You'll have to read all the data and sort it anyway, so this shouldn't have a penalty over any other method of deriving this.  This should limit you to one sort, but I don't have an instance of Snowflake to test.  It'll be two at max, second shouldn't be that expensive:

```
WITH product_summary AS
(
  SELECT
    comb.productID
   ,comb.trxnWeekStartDate
   ,COALESCE
      (
        MAX
          (
            CASE
              WHEN comb.source = 1 THEN comb.dollarAmt
             ELSE NULL
            END
          )
       ,MAX
          (
            CASE
              WHEN comb.source = 2 THEN comb.dollarAmt
              ELSE NULL
            END
          )
       ) AS dollarAmt
   ,MAX
      (
        CASE
          WHEN MIN(comb.source) = 1 THEN comb.trxnWeekStartDate
          ELSE '1901-01-01'
        END
      )
      OVER
        (
          PARTITION BY
            comb.ProductID
          ORDER BY
            comb.trxnWeekStartDate
        ) AS MinIncludeDate
  FROM
    (
      SELECT
        productID
       ,trxnWeekStartDate
       ,dollarAmt
       ,1 AS Source
      FROM
        sales_primary

        UNION ALL

      SELECT
        productID
       ,trxnWeekStartDate
       ,dollarAmt
       ,2 AS Source
      FROM
        sales_secondary
    ) comb
  GROUP BY
    comb.productID
   ,comb.trxnWeekStartDate
)
SELECT
  productID
 ,trxnWeekStartDate
 ,dollarAmt
FROM
  product_summary
QUALIFY
  /* If no lapse, number of weeks since last source 1 date will be the row number - 1 */
  trxnWeekStartDate = DATEADD(WEEK,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY productID, MinIncludeDate ORDER BY trxnWeekStartDate) - 1,MinIncludeDate)
```

Updated fiddle here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=001e276d0e36680b88eb5a650bee6c81

Comment: I freehanded this in between meetings so if there is a syntax error or something doesn't look right, let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think this satisfies requirement #4 - if some secondary record is included for this week, then next week we treat this secondary record as if it were primary when applying the logic to next week's secondary records.

Comment: Please see my latest example in question

Comment: @Ryan Ok, I see now.  Answer is updated.

Comment: Thanks for the update and this is quite informative. I still have question about the third branch within `CASE`: `WHEN LAG(comb.trxnWeekStartDate) OVER (PARTITION BY comb.productId ORDER BY comb.trxnWeekStartDate) = DATEADD(DAY,-7,comb.trxnWeekStartDate) THEN 'Y'` - if there is any discontinuation (see added example of sales of product 123 in March), we should not include the march rows in our result, because 1. the first march row will be correctly marked as "N" by the above logic, and 2. the second March row should look at the prior week only, and the first march row is "N".

Comment: @Ryan - Okay, I see now, there may need to be another layer on top since Snowflake doesn't support something like `RESET WHEN` like Teradata does.  Let me think on it for a bit to see if there's a more elegant solution.

Comment: I came up with a solution using another layer here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=0be219bd601e204ce6eab4fac8ff23bd . An equivalent logic I'm thinking right now is - we essentially need to identify the "gaps" within data. If a primary record marks the start of the gap then no problem; but if a secondary record starts a gap then we need to discard all following records until a primary one. It still needs multiple layers of subqueries though.

Comment: And thanks for mentioning `RESET WHEN` - I used Teradata before but I did not know that.

Comment: @Ryan - let me review to make sure there aren't any edge cases lurking.

Comment: @Ryan - Sorry for the delay, was busy all week.  Updated the answer - no edge cases to handle with the new code since we're testing the requirement directly.